# selenium ide chrome how to save to csv file

Tags: csv, selenium-chromedriver, export-to-csv, selenium-ide

I am currently using selenium ide for chrome and I was wondering if it's possible to save text from a given class to a csv file.

I try the command csvSave but Selenium Ide doesn't recognize it.

I did store id="some class name" !csvLine which give me no error. How can I get this input to save into a csv file.

Comment: csvSave works wih UI.vision chrome extension not the Selenium IDE